# angularjs - checkbox status controlling from remote data

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-checked

Im trying to make a notification configuration page. Basically the user should be able to choose what kind of notifications he wishes to receive for a specific module. There are 3 types of notifications (Email, SMS and UI). Currently my array is build like this

```
$scope.modules= [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Module1",
            "notifications": [
                {
                    "notification": "email"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Module2",
            "notifications": [
                {
                    "notification": "sms"
                },
                {
                    "notification": "ui"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

I'm trying to achieve this view

[image]

The problem:
When I am trying to repeat notifications of a certain module, if for example {"notification": "email"} doest not exist, the checkbox does not stay unchecked, but instead is removed from the view.

Any ideas how to perform the ng-repeat? Thanks

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GranitS/rqbm6e8b/)

Comment: Could you put your code in a fiddle/plunkr ?

Comment: @MartijnWelker i updated my question, fiddle is there

Answer (score 2):

The structure is somewhat wrong. Why not have an Array of Objects for notifications like below:

```
"notifications": [ {"sms": true}, {"email": false}, {"ui": true} ];
```

It would be easy enough to iterate and set then.

Iterate over `$scope.modules` and for each such module, have three checkboxes inside the wrapping `ng-repeat` div. Then set it checked / unchecked depending upon notification in `notifications`.

```
<span>Email</span>    <span>Ui</span>    <span>Sms</span>
<div ng-repeat="module in modules">
    {{ module.name }}
    <div ng-repeat="notification in module.notifications">
        <!-- Email -->
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="notification.email" />
        <!-- Ui -->
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="notification.ui" />
        <!-- Sms -->
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="notification.sms" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, and I really like the solution, but i dont want add another column in my database @softvar